# Start a Kickstart run from a running Live CD?

Tags: fedora, system-installation

Due to some strange bugs in the Fedora bootloader, I cannot install my system using a LUKS container and BTRFS. Hopefully this is fixed for Fedora 24, but I'm not waiting :)

I came across [this helpful article](https://blog.laimbock.com/2014/12/27/howto-kickstart-fedora-with-luks-encrypted-partitions/) which describes how to have Kickstarter install Fedora, setting up LUKS and creating partitions as it goes. I'm planning on testing something like this inside of a virtual machine at first to make sure I lock down the process before I go to physical media.

If I'm going to be experimenting with this in VirtualBox, what are my options for getting the Kickstarter config into the VM? I know I can setup NFS or have a physical USB device with the file on it, but is there a way for me to boot the Fedora LiveCD and then download the file over HTTPS or `scp` it over from another machine? Is there a good way of doing this?

I imagine it's going to take some time to get Kickstarter down, so this will be a trial and error process.

Answer (score 0):

You can point to a kickstart file in a number of ways, including http

url — Install from an installation tree on a remote server via FTP, HTTP, or HTTPS.
For example:

`url --url http://<server>/<dir>`

or:

`url --url ftp://<username>:<password>@<server>/<dir>`

Source: [RedHat Kickstart Configuation documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html)